# How to use auto increment id with Entitiy Framework 6 and PostgreSQL not EF CORE?

Tags: postgresql, frameworks, entity-framework-6, entity, auto-increment

I have MVC Framework Project with EF6 and POSTGRESQL. I'm using database first and create edmx file from database.

```
public partial class MinimalEarthEntities : DbContext
{
    public MinimalEarthEntities()
        : base("name=MinimalEarthEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
}
public partial class User
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string GSM { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

These code was generated from EF6. ID column is auto increment value. But EF6 can not be instert data due to auto increment not working.

Is there anybody help to solve this problem?

Comment: Add the attribute [DatabaseGenerated(Identity)] to your Id, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/data-annotations#databasegenerated

Comment: Did you solve the problem? If you did, could you please share with us?